# Flutter compilation error when trying to run android emulator with json_serializable package

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to use the json serializable package for flutter but i get a compilation error. Below is a example of my Model file.

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'Location.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Location{
  final String name;
  final String location;

  Location({this.name, this.location});

  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>_$LocationFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LocationToJson(this);
}
```

Below is the part Location.g.dart file generated

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'Location.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

Location _$LocationFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Location(
    name: json['name'] as String,
    location: json['location'] as String,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$LocationToJson(Location instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'name': instance.name,
      'location': instance.location,
    };
```

However upon trying to run my emulator, i get the compilation error,

```
Compiler message:
lib/Models/location.dart:3:6: Error: Using 'lib/Models/Location.g.dart' as part of 'package:VendorApp/Models/location.dart' but its 'part of' declaration says 'package:VendorApp/Models/Location.dart'.
part 'Location.g.dart';
     ^
lib/Models/location.dart:12:58: Error: Method not found: '_$LocationFromJson'.
  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>_$LocationFromJson(json);
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/Models/location.dart:13:36: Error: The method '_$LocationToJson' isn't defined for the class 'Location'.
 - 'Location' is from 'package:VendorApp/Models/location.dart' ('lib/Models/location.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named '_$LocationToJson'.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LocationToJson(this);
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:

```
part 'Location.g.dart';
```

to:

```
part 'location.g.dart';
```

Comment: Thanks, i didnt notice the file had lowercase names

Comment: The compiler error message had it all explained, it even placed a `^` on the `L` so you could know.

Comment: Although every time i run it shows a popup warning saying build errors exist but if i ignore them the app runs, is there any way around this?